# Use cUrl with Chrome remote debugging

Tags: curl, chrome-remote-debugging

I'm trying to connect to Chrome remote debuging with cUrl, however, responses from Chrome return "200 OK" but no data.

I set up chrome using:

```
chrome.exe --headless --remote-debugging-port=12345
```

I can successfully get a list of pages with:

```
>curl -i "http://localhost:12345/json"

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length:612
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
[ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:12345/devtools/page/19d24d3a-25b7-4ee8-a5cf-4f3d17778575",
  ...
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:12345/devtools/page/19d24d3a-25b7-4ee8-a5cf-4f3d17778575"
} ]
```

However, I can only get empty successful response from debugger URLs:

```
>echo {"id":0,"method":"Page.navigate","params":{"url":"https://stackoverflow.com/"}}|curl -i "http://localhost:12345/devtools/page/19d24d3a-25b7-4ee8-a5cf-4f3d17778575" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d -

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain
```

Commands like `Page.navigate` and also misformed requests return `200 OK` but nothing is performed.

What I'm I missing???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use websockets to manage chrome like that. Quoting [chromedevtools.github.io](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/):

> Your application can discover available pages by requesting:
>   http://localhost:9222/json and getting a JSON object with information
>   about inspectable pages along with the WebSocket addresses that you
>   could use in order to start instrumenting them

This is how it would work (at least on my Mac):

#### Run Chrome

```
docker pull deepsweet/chromium-headless-remote:69
docker run -it --rm -p 9222:9222 deepsweet/chromium-headless-remote:69
```

#### Fetching WebSocket addresses

```
curl -i "http://localhost:9222/json"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length:361
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8

[ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/DC33B65CA373BE2770F2A1031C3B4CBF",
   "id": "DC33B65CA373BE2770F2A1031C3B4CBF",
   "title": "about:blank",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "about:blank",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/DC33B65CA373BE2770F2A1031C3B4CBF"
} ]
```

#### Sending your command

```
echo '{ "id":2, "method":"Page.navigate", "params":{"url": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"} }' | websocat -t - ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/DC33B65CA373BE2770F2A1031C3B4CBF
```

[websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat) is used in the example. You can also write a simple script to do it like [here](https://www.igvita.com/2012/04/09/driving-google-chrome-via-websocket-api/)

#### Make sure the page is opened

```
curl -i "http://localhost:9222/json"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length:432
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8

[ {
   "description": "",
   "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "/devtools/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/DC33B65CA373BE2770F2A1031C3B4CBF",
   "id": "DC33B65CA373BE2770F2A1031C3B4CBF",
   "title": "Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, &amp; Build Careers",
   "type": "page",
   "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/DC33B65CA373BE2770F2A1031C3B4CBF"
} ]
```

Comment: Yep, you're right. Replacing `ws://` with `http://` should made some bell ring, but I didn't hear it...